# Conditions in modeler field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I want to check a vector file if there is a column "Source".

If yes, nothing to do. If there is no column "Source" it should be created and filled up with '0'.

Is this possible to do via the modeler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create a new script from:

   ```
   Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script
   ```
2. Use something like the following:

   ```
   ##Example=name
   ##Layer=vector

   from qgis.core import QgsField
   from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

   layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
   idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('Source')

   if idx != -1:
       pass
   else:
       layer.startEditing()
       layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Source", QVariant.Int) ] )
       layer.updateFields()
       for feat in layer.getFeatures():
           layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), layer.fieldNameIndex('Source'), '0')
       layer.commitChanges()
   ```
3. Save the script in your `C:/Users/You/.qgis2/processing/scripts/` directory. Then you should be able to call this script in your modeler.

Comment: @Pimpel - Most welcome, glad it helped =)